# What is the Vim shortcut on Mac to expand emmet snippet?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, macos

I am in newbie to Neovim.

I have tried CMD Y but it is not working.

Comment: Did you solve your question? Is the answer solve your problem? If so maybe could you accept the solution using the v green button next to the arrow voting button. It help the question to rest :-)

Comment: It's not "CMD Y", it's "CTRL Y".

Comment: @romainl "CTRL Y" also does not work.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make <kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd> expand the Emmet snippets I had (on Windows 10) to add the following line into `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key='<C-y>'
```

For make <kbd>Cmd-y</kbd> expand the Emmet snippets on Mac you should probably add the following line into `init.vim`:

```
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key='<D-y>'
```

Or in `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`:

```
vim.g.user_emmet_expandabbr='<D-y>'
```

Remark: One way to have `vim-plug` installed on MacOs for Neovim is to run in a console the following commands:

```
curl -fLo ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

I got the information from: [Neovim for MacOS](https://dev.to/dafloresdiaz/neovim-for-macos-3nk0)

Remark: to have Emmet installed you need to:

1. Have the Plug emmet command in your `init.vim`:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
call plug#end()
```

2. Restart Neovim
3. Run the `:PlugInstall` command

Comment: When I try to install emmet using vim plug it gives me the following two errors: E117: Unknown function: plug#begin and E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks that `vm-plug` is not installed correctly.

Comment: I am using neovim.

Comment: Now neovim is giving this error: E492: Not an editor command: PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC

Comment: What is the content of the `~/.vim/autoload` folder? Does it contains a `plug.vim` file?

Comment: It does not contain any folder.

Comment: My mistake for Neovim o  MacOs you shou look at: `~/.local/share/nvim/autoload/plug.vim`

Comment: After the command ~curl -fLo ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim~ I was able to install vim-plug. Now how to install emmet?

Comment: Emmet-vim was installed but I cannot get to expand the snippets.

Comment: What is the value of `g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key`? What is the result of:`:echo g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key`?

Comment: Don't know. Should be the default key, whatever it is.

Comment: Can you tell me the result of the proposed command: `:echo g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key`?

Comment: It gives `E121: Undefined variable g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key`.

Comment: Good! Now you could go back to the answer and make the modification to the `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` proposed. It will define the variable that define the shortcut used by Emmet to expand the snippet.

Comment: It works now! One more question: there is a command in which vim drops support for legacy computers. Is there such a command for neovim?

Comment: Great :-) Can you tell me which command you are referring to in Vim? Could you tell me what is 'legacy computers' in this context?

Comment: If the solution works for you could you validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting button. It help the question resting :-)

Comment: While I did not find the command I found something similar: https://github.com/wookayin/dotfiles/issues/36

Comment: Do you want a command to get the version number of Neovim? What is the version number of Neovim you are using? What is the concern you have about backward compatibility (which plugin, which feature)?

Comment: Does backward compatibility slow down neovim? If yes, is there a command to remove it?

Comment: Both Vim and Neovim pay à lot of attention to backward  compatibilité. There are no flag to get rid of it. However there is a setting to switch both neovim and vim from the 'full' backward compatibilité with vi.

Comment: What is this setting?

Comment: `set nocompatible`

Comment: Thanks! That was the command I was looking for.

Comment: `'set nocompatible'` is ignored in Neovim, as [it is always "nocompatible"](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#'compatible').